# Android. Remote the android tv box from a remote control

Tags: java, android, android-layout

You have propaply seen those pretty cheap android tv boxes available on the market. They are usually followed with a remote control that has some functionalities like clicking, swipe or slide to left and right up and down.

Recently i made an app and tried to navigate it using the remote control.  I have some gesture methods in the project. I tried to swipe to left and right but the app didnt do anything while when i try it on my phone that has a screen gets the gesture and do what it should. Like opening the navigation drawer etc.

Now to my question: does one need to use speciel methods? Is there some rules that one should be ware of?

**Edit**
This is what Ive done so far. I made a class that defines the action: It's from google.developer

```
    public class Dpad {
        public final static int UP = 0;
        public final static int LEFT = 1;
        public final static int RIGHT = 2;
        public final static int DOWN = 3;
        public final static int CENTER = 4;

        int directionPressed = -1; // initialized to -1

        public int getDirectionPressed(InputEvent event) {
            if (!isDpadDevice(event)) {
                return -1;
            }

            // If the input event is a MotionEvent, check its hat axis values.
            if (event instanceof MotionEvent) {

                // Use the hat axis value to find the D-pad direction
                MotionEvent motionEvent = (MotionEvent) event;
                float xaxis = motionEvent.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_HAT_X);
                float yaxis = motionEvent.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_HAT_Y);

                // Check if the AXIS_HAT_X value is -1 or 1, and set the D-pad
                // LEFT and RIGHT direction accordingly.
                if (Float.compare(xaxis, -1.0f) == 0) {
                    directionPressed = Dpad.LEFT;
                } else if (Float.compare(xaxis, 1.0f) == 0) {
                    directionPressed = Dpad.RIGHT;
                }
                // Check if the AXIS_HAT_Y value is -1 or 1, and set the D-pad
                // UP and DOWN direction accordingly.
                else if (Float.compare(yaxis, -1.0f) == 0) {
                    directionPressed = Dpad.UP;
                } else if (Float.compare(yaxis, 1.0f) == 0) {
                    directionPressed = Dpad.DOWN;
                }
            }

            // If the input event is a KeyEvent, check its key code.
            else if (event instanceof KeyEvent) {

                // Use the key code to find the D-pad direction.
                KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) event;
                if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
                    directionPressed = Dpad.LEFT;
                } else if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
                    directionPressed = Dpad.RIGHT;
                } else if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
                    directionPressed = Dpad.UP;
                } else if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
                    directionPressed = Dpad.DOWN;
                } else if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                    directionPressed = Dpad.CENTER;
                }
            }
            return directionPressed;
        }

        public static boolean isDpadDevice(InputEvent event) {
            // Check that input comes from a device with directional pads.
            if ((event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD)
                    != InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

In my MainActivity I have a navigationdrawer. which I want to open and close when remotecontrol D-pad wants it

```
 mDrawerLayout.setOnGenericMotionListener(new View.OnGenericMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGenericMotion(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (Dpad.isDpadDevice(motionEvent)) {
                int press = mDpad.getDirectionPressed(motionEvent);
                switch (press) {
                    case Dpad.RIGHT:
                        // Do something for UP direction press Open the drawer
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                        return true;
                    case Dpad.LEFT:

                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                        return true;

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In one of the fragments I have a media player and using D-pad up and D-pad down I change the video.

```
    v.setOnGenericMotionListener(new View.OnGenericMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGenericMotion(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (Dpad.isDpadDevice(motionEvent)) {
                int press = mDpad.getDirectionPressed(motionEvent);
                switch (press) {
                    case Dpad.UP:
                        // Do something for UP direction press
                        UP(); // Change the video to next
                        return true;
                    case Dpad.DOWN:
                        DOWN(); // Change the video the earlier on
                        return true;

                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**
It' now become a problem since it doesn't response to any motion. I tried on a emulator with physical keyboard and not a single action happens. I would appritiate if someone gives me a hint.
 i mean this kind of remote control in the picture below [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry to ask but have you searched on it?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the Nexus Player (which is an Android TV), its Bluetooth remote control has a D-pad (that's the technical term, it means Directional-pad, and D-pad is what you should be searching for in the official documentation for Android TV). See https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input.html#dpad

Comment: @Elltz one of my problems is that i dont know what to search for. What key word to use :( i end up with remote control apps

Comment: Here. Take a look at this code. This is what was used for the Google TV (the precursor to Android TV). It was written by a Google TV Developer Advocate. I have no idea if this project is still relevant now or even works anymore on the new Android TVs. But it's probably worth a look anyway. https://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/

Comment: I had developed the same application for samsunage Googel TV. I think it can possible using https://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/. I had used the same thing for develoepd the custom remote control. About gesture this app has implemented the gesture from left to right.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar hi. No that protocoll is to use mobile as a remote . Thats not what i want. And the docs are very poor

Comment: The Protocol in that library is design for communicate with Google TV Sdk. When I was design the Remote application we had used this for the same thing.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar do you kkow any documentation. There is n8 docs there. Is 8t really what i wan? Plz look t my lst update

Answer (score 0):

I think the code on Android Developer is wrong:

```
public static boolean isDpadDevice(InputEvent event) {
    // Check that input comes from a device with directional pads.
    if ((event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD)
         != InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
}
```

The condition should be "==" instead of "!=", so this is correct:

```
    public static boolean isDpadDevice(InputEvent event) {
    // Check that input comes from a device with directional pads.
    if ((event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD)
         == InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 }
```